# Conditional formatting three lowest values if cell is equal to a value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I want to highlight the rows with the three lowest values in Column D if the value in Column A is `100`. For example:

```
Column A        D
       30       2
     **100      8**
       50       20
     **100      10**
       100      50 
     **100      12**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try selecting A1:A6 and D1:D6 then Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., Custom formula is:

```
=and($A1=100,MATCH($D1,query($A$1:$D$6,"select D where A=100 order by D asc limit 3"),0))
```

choose formatting and click <kbd>Done</kbd>.